# How to split value of parameter in ssrs

Tags: c#, reporting-services, split

"&emplid="+emplid+"&site="+Site +"

[This is my parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIzxi.png)

The problem here is my report have the parameter values from url above but it doesn't work to while I press the view report button
For example: A11111,B22222,C33333 <- this is what I get from url

but to activate the report parameter value should be
A11111,
B22222,
C33333
Should I try to use split function in ssrs?

Comment: You can use expression and split fuction to split the parameter. Have a look at this page: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28428.passing-multi-value-parameter-to-ssrs-report-using-url.aspx

Comment: Please edit your question and show the full URL you are using and also show the dataset query where the parameter is used.